# 4.3.1. Transaction Receipt-Yellow Paper

Tags: transactions, blocks, yellow-paper

I am trying to understand the following function which appears in section 4.3.1 of the Ethereum Yellow Paper:

[image: 4.3.1 Ethereum Yellow Paper]
The function description state it **"prepares"** a transaction receipt, does it mean that the function does not actually perform the **RLP encoding**?. What is the purpose of this function?.
Any pointers would be great,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is what you say the function doesn't actually perform the RLP encoding. The function is just transform a transaction receipt into a new list contain:

- 0: The constant 0
- Ru: the cumulative gas
- Rb: Bloom filter composed
- Rl: the set of logs

This function is just like what they call it prepare to be transform into RLP-serialize. If you look up ahead at this function:

```
Ht ≡ TRIE({∀i < ||BT||, i ∈ N : p(i, LT (BT[i]))})

p(k, v) ≡ (RLP(k), RLP(v))
```

Now you can easily understand that LT(BT[i]) mean the prepare for the RLP-serialize for each receipt in BT and then the function p use RLP-encode on it.

If they didn't define that earlier the function will be a lot uglier than it is (which is already very ugly).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Makes sense